# SIM808 GPS+GSM Vehicle Tracking using Maduino Zero SIM808 GPS Tracker V3.5

Tags: gsm, gps

I'm learning about GPS technology and I bought the Maduino Zero SIM808 board V3.5 to design a vehicle tracker. I have found source code for the project online.  After I upload the code to Maduino board, the code executes fine.

I'm sending "Location" to the device and i'm expecting reply with google map on my phone to be able to check device location, but i'm not getting reply from the device. i have changed the AT commands to test if i will get reply from the device, here is the source where i got the project: https://how2electronics.com/gps-gsm-based-vehicle-tracking-system-using-arduino/

Here is my output from the code:

```
Text Mode: ON
GPS Intializing…
GPS Initialized
Location:
Send sms to get the location
```

```cpp
#include<string.h>
 
#define DEBUG true
 
int PWR_KEY = 9;
int RST_KEY = 6;
int LOW_PWR_KEY = 5;
 
String msg = String("");
int SmsContentFlag = 0;
String mob;
String loct;
void setup()
{
  pinMode(PWR_KEY, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RST_KEY, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LOW_PWR_KEY, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(RST_KEY, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LOW_PWR_KEY, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(PWR_KEY, HIGH);
 
  //      String msg = String("");
  //    int SmsContentFlag = 0;
 
  SerialUSB.begin(115200);
  Serial1.begin(115200);
  //modulePowerOn();
  delay(2000);
  SerialUSB.println("Checking Module...");
  int i = 1;
  String res;
  while (i) {
    Serial1.println("AT");
    while (Serial1.available() > 0) {
      if (Serial1.find("OK"))
        i = 0;
    }
    delay(500);
  }
  SerialUSB.println("Module Connected");
  //GprsTextModeSMS();
  SerialUSB.print("Text Mode: ");
  i = 1;
  while (i) {
    Serial1.println("AT+CSMP=17,167,0,0");
    delay(100);
    Serial1.println("AT+CMGF=1\r");
    while (Serial1.available() > 0) {
      if (Serial1.find("OK"))
        i = 0;
    }
    delay(500);
  }
  SerialUSB.println("ON");
  Serial1.println("AT+CGNSPWR=1");
  delay(100);
  Serial1.println("AT+CGNSSEQ=RMC");
  SerialUSB.println("GPS Intializing...");
  delay(5000);
  SerialUSB.println("GPS Initialized");
  SerialUSB.flush();
  i = 1;
  String str;
  while (i) {
    Serial1.println("AT+CGPSINF=0");
    delay(100);
    while (Serial1.available() <= 0);
    if (Serial1.find("AT+CGPSINF=0")) {
      str = Serial1.readString();
      //SerialUSB.println(str);
      i = 0;
    }
    delay(500);
  }
  loct = str.substring(4, 23);
  SerialUSB.print("Location: ");
  SerialUSB.println(loct);
  //while(1);
  SerialUSB.println("Send sms to get the location");
}
 
 
void loop()
{
  char SerialInByte;
 
  if (Serial1.available())
  {
    //char SerialInByte;
    SerialInByte = (unsigned char)Serial1.read();
    if ( SerialInByte == 13 ) //0x0D
    {
      ProcessGprsMsg();
    }
    if ( SerialInByte == 10 )
    {
    }
    else
    {
      //EN: store the current character in the message string buffer
      msg += String(SerialInByte);
    }
  }
  if (SmsContentFlag == 1) {
    int i;
    SerialUSB.println("Flag Cleared");
    SerialUSB.print("Message: ");
    SerialUSB.println(msg);
    if (msg.indexOf("Location")) {
      SerialUSB.println("Message Received");
      i = msg.indexOf("+27");
      //SerialUSB.print("index: ");
      //SerialUSB.println(i);
      //SerialUSB.println(msg[i+1]);
      i = i + 3;
      for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++, i++) {
        mob += msg[i];
      }
      SerialUSB.print("Mobile: ");
      SerialUSB.println(mob);
      String cmd = "AT+CMGS=\"";
      cmd += mob;
      cmd += "\"";
      cmd += "\r";
      Serial1.println(cmd);
      delay(100);
 
      Serial1.print("Your Vehicle Current Location ");
      Serial1.print(loct);
      Serial1.print("\n");
      Serial1.print("Check Map: \n");
      Serial1.print(" https://www.google.com/maps/@");
      Serial1.println(loct);
      Serial1.println((char)26);
      delay(1000);
    }
    ClearGprsMsg();
    SmsContentFlag = 0;
    msg.remove(0);
    mob.remove(0);
  }
  delay(100);
}
 
 
// EN: Request Text Mode for SMS messaging
void GprsTextModeSMS()
{
  Serial1.println( "AT+CMGF=1" );
}
 
void GprsReadSmsStore( String SmsStorePos )
{
  // Serial.print( "GprsReadSmsStore for storePos " );
  // Serial.println( SmsStorePos );
  Serial1.print( "AT+CMGR=" );
  Serial1.println( SmsStorePos );
}
 
// EN: Clear the GPRS shield message buffer
void ClearGprsMsg()
{
  msg = "";
}
 
// EN: interpret the GPRS shield message and act appropiately
void ProcessGprsMsg()
{
  SerialUSB.println("");
  //  Serial.print( "GPRS Message: [" );
  SerialUSB.print( msg );
  //    Serial.println( "]" );
  if ( msg.indexOf( "Call Ready" ) >= 0 )
  {
    SerialUSB.println( "*** GPRS Shield registered on Mobile Network ***" );
    GprsTextModeSMS();
  }
 
  //EN: unsolicited message received when getting a SMS message
  if ( msg.indexOf( "+CIEV" ) >= 0 )
  {
    SerialUSB.println( "*** SMS Received ***" );
  }
 
  //EN: SMS store readed through UART (result of GprsReadSmsStore request)
  if ( msg.indexOf( "+CMT:" ) >= 0 )
  {
    // EN: Next message will contains the BODY of SMS
    SmsContentFlag = 1;
    // EN: Following lines are essentiel to not clear the flag!
    //ClearGprsMsg();
    return;
  }
 
  // EN: +CMGR message just before indicate that the following GRPS Shield message
  //     (this message) will contains the SMS body
  if ( SmsContentFlag == 1 )
  {
    SerialUSB.println( "*** SMS MESSAGE CONTENT ***" );
    SerialUSB.println( msg );
    SerialUSB.println( "*** END OF SMS MESSAGE ***" );
    //ProcessSms( msg );
  }
 
  /*ClearGprsMsg();
    //EN: Always clear the flag
    SmsContentFlag = 0; */
}
```

Comment: Did you mean "device will **not** reply with google map link"?  It's not clear (to me anyway) what the problem is that you're suggesting may have something to do with your network connection.

Comment: I'm sending "Location" to the device and i'm expecting reply with google map to be able to check device location, but i'm not getting reply from the device.  i have changed the AT commands to test if i will get reply from the device, here is the source where i got the project: https://how2electronics.com/gps-gsm-based-vehicle-tracking-system-using-arduino/

Comment: remove all GPS code ... reduce your code to only a simple text reply ... something like `receive any text, reply "hello world"`